# Show that there exists $F_k \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $A \subset \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k \text{ and } m^*(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k )= m^*(A).$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ be any set. Assume $m^*(A) < \infty.$ Show that there exists open sets $F_k \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $$A \subset \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k \text{ and } m^*(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k )= m^*(A).$$

It appears that for each $k \in \Bbb N$ we can cover $A$ with $\{I_{k,n}\}_n$ intervals. Now by definition of the outer measure (infimum) we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_{k,n}) \le m^*(A) + \frac{1}{k}.$$

If we now define $F_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_{k,n}$ it seems that for any $k$ this defined $F_n$ is a cover now for $A$(?) so $A \subset \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_n$. Taking the intersection $$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_{k,n}\right)$$  we have that $$m^*(A) \le m^*(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_n) \le m^*(F_n) = m^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_{k,n}) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_{k,n}) \le m^*(A) + \frac1k$$ so since $m^*(A) \le m^*(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_n) \le  m^*(A) + \frac1k$ for any $k$ we get that $m^*(A) =  m^*(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_n)$.

Couple of questions:

> How is it that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_{k,n}) \le m^*(A) + \frac{1}{k}?$$ The actual definition is that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_{n}) \le m^*(A) + \varepsilon$$ which follows from the infimum of the outer measure.

> What is the role of $k$ here? It seems as if we would have $k$ (countable) many covers for $A$, but this isn't neccessarily true? How do we know we can cover $A$ with countable many covers?

Comment: Just take $\epsilon =\frac  1k$ and you will get intervals $I_{nk}, n=1,2,...$ that depend on $k$.